# Subfloating images with same margins left/middle/right

Tags: spacing, graphics

Currently I have the following code:

```
\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\subfloat[htb][left]{\fcolorbox{plotBord}{plotPadd}{\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{figs/bla1.png}}}
\hfill
\subfloat[htb][right]{\fcolorbox{plotBord}{plotPadd}{\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{figs/bla2.png}}}
\caption[bla]{foobar}
\end{figure}
```

Which displays the two images on the left and right end of the text (because of `\hfill`). If I use something like `\hspace{10px}` instead, the two images have a certain distance between them in the middle, but the margin to the left and right end of the text width is bigger than the one in the middle. Is there any way to always align two images so that they have the same margins left/middle/right like that:

[image: sketch]

The two images always have the same size, but I'll add a border and a certain padding to it by using `\fcolorbox{}`.

Comment: Please always use the "Add Image" icon above the text box to add images. I did this for you now. This uploads them using a special stackexchange imgur.com account which ensures that the image won't be deleted after 6 month. If you do it manually your image might disappear after a while. See the [related discussion on Meta.TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1440/how-do-we-repair-gonzalo-medinas-posts-containing-images) for more information.

Comment: Okay tanks, didn't see any 'Add image' link because I especially looked for one... But  I must have been blind, because I looked for a link and not for an image; now I saw it... Thanks

Comment: There is also a CTRL+G shortcut for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use two more `\hfill`s; the last one requires "something" (`\null`, which is simply an abbreviation for `\hbox{}`) to have effect. Another option (see egreg's comment) is to use `\hspace{\fill}` instead of `\hfill` and `\hspace*{\fill}` instead of the last `\hfill\null` (now, `\null` is not required). The following example shows both approaches:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor,subfig}

\colorlet{plotBord}{red}
\colorlet{plotPadd}{blue}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\hspace{\fill}%
\subfloat[htb][left]{\fcolorbox{plotBord}{plotPadd}{\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{figs/bla1.png}}}
\hspace{\fill}%
\subfloat[htb][right]{\fcolorbox{plotBord}{plotPadd}{\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{figs/bla2.png}}}
\hspace*{\fill}%
\caption[bla]{foobar}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\hfill
\subfloat[htb][left]{\fcolorbox{plotBord}{plotPadd}{\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{figs/bla1.png}}}
\hfill
\subfloat[htb][right]{\fcolorbox{plotBord}{plotPadd}{\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{figs/bla2.png}}}
\hfill\null
\caption[bla]{foobar}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The `demo` option for `graphicx` was only used to make my example compilable for everyone (do not use that option in your actual document). I also defined the colors `plotBord` and `plotPadd`. The `showframe` option for `geometry` was used to draw a frame for visualization purposes. Only the relevant part is shown in the following image:

[image]

Comment: What about `\hspace*{\fill}` instead of the undocumented `\null`?

Comment: Sorry to insist, but the last one should be `\hspace*{\fill}`; try and put a `%` after it. It's quite interesting to understand why it works without the `%`. There are also some spurious spaces in your input.

Comment: @egreg: I hope this time the example code is OK. I couldn't detect the spurious spaces you mentioned.

Comment: You catched those after `\hspace{\fill}`, but missed the ones after `\subfloat[...]{...}`. The last one, after `\hspace*{\fill}` is irrelevant because `\end{figure}` (or `\caption`) causes the end of the paragraph and a glob of glue at the end of the paragraph is gobbled anyway (this explains why `\hspace{\fill}` without `*` and `%` works, while `\hfill` without a `\null` doesn't).

Comment: @egreg: I thought about those spaces after `\subfloat[]{}` too, but I cannot see any difference in the output whether I use `%` to remove those spaces or not. Am I misssing something?

Comment: Okay thanks, I took the second example with the `\hfill[...]\hfill[...]\hfill\null`. Is there any difference in which I take in terms of `better coding style` or compatibility or something else?! Or just completely irrelevant?

Comment: @Marc Edlo: \fill is a LaTeX length defined as `\fill = 0pt plus 1fill` and `\hfill` is equivalent to `\hskip 0cm plus 1fill` so (AFAIK) `\hspace{\fill}` and `\hfill` are equivalent.